# Given Lat and Lon identify if point over land or ocean using R

Tags: r, coordinates

In R, how do I identify if a point is over land or ocean?

e.g. for:

```
set.seed(0)
lat <- runif(10, -80, 80)
lon <- runif(10, -180, 180)
points <- expand.grid(lat, lon)
```

I would like to create a column called "Land" of type "logical".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here in 2020, an answer that uses the **sf** package:

```r
library(sf)
library(spData) ## For `world`, an sf MULTIPOLYGON object

## Create an sf POINTS object
set.seed(0)
lat <- runif(10, -80, 80)
lon <- runif(10, -180, 180)
points <- expand.grid(lon, lat)  # Note that I reversed OP's ordering of lat/long
pts <- st_as_sf(points, coords=1:2, crs=4326)

## Find which points fall over land
ii <- !is.na(as.numeric(st_intersects(pts, world)))

## Check that it worked
plot(st_geometry(world))
plot(pts, col=1+ii, pch=16, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

---

Original 2012 answer, using the **sp** package:

```r
## One example of a SpatialPolygons object mapping Earth's land areas
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
    
## Create a SpatialPoints object
set.seed(0)
lat <- runif(10, -80, 80)
lon <- runif(10, -180, 180)
points <- expand.grid(lon, lat)  # Note that I reversed OP's ordering of lat/long
pts <- SpatialPoints(points, proj4string=CRS(proj4string(wrld_simpl)))
    
## Find which points fall over land
ii <- !is.na(over(pts, wrld_simpl)$FIPS)
    
## Check that it worked
plot(wrld_simpl)
points(pts, col=1+ii, pch=16)
```

[image]