# Find Lat and Long points on land only

Tags: r, coordinates, array

I'm new to R and GIS so please forgive me if this is a simple request.

I was looking for a way to find out if a Lat/Long point is on land or ocean. I found this previous post from a couple of years ago which provides an array of true/false results.

[Given a Lat and Lon, identify if the point is over land or ocean?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75033/given-a-lat-and-lon-identify-if-the-point-is-over-land-or-ocean)

I was able to get it to display the simple world map with the points, but I had two questions:

How do I use the rworldmap with the more detailed and up to date country polygons?
How do I return only the Lat/Long points that are on land?

Basically I am looking to get the Lat/Long points that are on land only and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out it is a single line of code. Using the example in the link, the line of code to only return the lat/long points that are on land is:

pts_land <- pts[c(ii)]

Where pts are all the lat/long points, ii is an array of true/false values and pts_land has all the lat/long points that are on land.